# Separate cell contents and distribute to different rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm given the following sample data:

| Item | Demand Qty | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 4 | SHORT NAS1291C02M RCVD 09/14 COMMIT: 2 W/S 09/29 + 2 W/S 09/30 |

Which tells me that, of the required 4 units, 2 will ship 9/29 and 2 more will ship 9/30.

I'm attempting to split the row by unit to give a ship date for each piece.  I've run the following code to split the line by quantity:

```
Sub ExpandRows()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    dat = rng
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = UBound(dat, 1) To 2 Step -1
        If dat(i, 3) > 1 Then
            Set rw = rng.Rows(i).EntireRow
            rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dat(i, 3) - 1).Insert
            rw.Copy rw.Offset(1, 0).Resize(dat(i, 3) - 1)
            rw.Cells(1, 3).Resize(dat(i, 3), 1) = 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So now I have this:

| Item | Demand Qty | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | SHORT NAS1291C02M RCVD 09/14 COMMIT: 2 W/S 09/29 + 2 W/S 09/30 |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | SHORT NAS1291C02M RCVD 09/14 COMMIT: 2 W/S 09/29 + 2 W/S 09/30 |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | SHORT NAS1291C02M RCVD 09/14 COMMIT: 2 W/S 09/29 + 2 W/S 09/30 |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | SHORT NAS1291C02M RCVD 09/14 COMMIT: 2 W/S 09/29 + 2 W/S 09/30 |

I need to distribute the dates from the comments column so that I'm left with this:

| Item | Demand Qty | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | W/S 09/29 |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | W/S 09/29 |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | W/S 09/30 |
| 69-55179-78 MOD A | 1 | W/S 09/30 |

I've scoured forums and how-to's and haven't been able to find anything that fits this situation.  The comments are different every time so I need to find the instances of "W/S" but I need the quantity before it and the date after and then insert a single date per row based on that quantity.
I'm kind of at a loss as I've been staring at this for 2 days now.
I know that the Stack isn't here to do it for me so I would consider an acceptable answer to be something that points me down a productive track.

*EDIT*
Here is a larger subset of the data I'm working with:

| Item | Demand Qty | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 115E5665G1 | 1 |  |
| 115E5684G1 | 1 |  |
| 115E6575G1 MOD A | 3 | 1 W/S 09/21+ 1 W/S 09/22+ 1 W/S 09/23 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | 1 W/S 09/15 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | 1 W/S 09/19 + 1 W/S 09/20 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | SHORT:115E6716G12 : 14-SEP-22 QTY 77 ETA 9/17 COMMIT: 1 W/S 09/21 + 1 W/S 09/22 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | SHORT:115E6716G12 : 14-SEP-22 QTY 77 ETA 9/17 COMMIT: 1 W/S 09/23 + 1 W/S 09/26 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | SHORT:115E6716G12 : 14-SEP-22 QTY 77 ETA 9/17 COMMIT: 1 W/S 09/27 + 1 W/S 09/28 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | SHORT:115E6716G12 : 14-SEP-22 QTY 77 ETA 9/17 COMMIT: 2 W/S 09/29 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 1 | SHORT:115E6716G12 : 14-SEP-22 QTY 77 ETA 9/17 COMMIT: 1 W/S 09/30 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | SHORT:115E6716G12 : 14-SEP-22 QTY 77 ETA 9/17 COMMIT: 2 W/S 10/03 |
| 115E6582G1 MOD A | 2 | SHORT:115E6716G12 : 14-SEP-22 QTY 77 ETA 9/17 COMMIT: 2 W/S 10/04 |

The comments come from an international sister facility so the formatting can be problematic.  I appreciate all the responses so far.  Just looking for that one that pushes me towards a working solution.

Comment: `find the instances of "W/S" but I need the quantity before it and the date after` you know exactly what to do. You can do this ^_^

Comment: Will it ever be the case that the number of W/S will not add up to `Demand Qty`. In other words, is it possible for `Demand Qty=3` with only a single W/S (`1 W/S 10/29`)? If that is the case, what do you want to do if there are more or fewer `W/S` than `Demand Qty`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes there will be instances where this is the case.  Any remaining lines will just be left blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure what you wanted to do if there was a mis-match between the `W/S count` and the `Demand Qty`.

The routine below will leave a blank comment for Items if there is insufficient `W/S`; or it will include a line with a blank `Demand Qty` if there are excessive `W/S`.

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***
*Edited to work with latest data sample**

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table10"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item", type text}, {"Demand Qty", Int64.Type}, {"Comments", type text}}),

//Replace nulls with "" to deal with empty Comments section
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type",null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Comments"}),

//for grouping
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Group by Item and Index
//   One way of dealing with more or fewer W/S than Demand Qty
    #"Group by Item" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Index","Item"},{
        {"new rows", (t)=> let
        //Create the expanded columns

        //Qty will always be 1
            Qty = List.Repeat({1}, t[Demand Qty]{0}),    

        //Create a List of the WS items by splitting on ":+ "
        //  and then retaining the items before and after an item that is W/S
            #"Split Comments" = List.Combine(List.Transform(t[Comments], each (Text.SplitAny(_,":+ ")))),

        //Positions of W/S
            WSpositions = List.PositionOf(#"Split Comments", "W/S", Occurrence.All),

        //Create a list of the Counts for each WS
            WScnts = List.Accumulate(WSpositions,{}, (state, current)=> state & {Number.From(#"Split Comments"{current-1})}),

        //Create a list of just the WS items
            WS = List.Accumulate(WSpositions,{}, (state,current)=> state & {Text.Combine(List.Range(#"Split Comments", current,2)," ")}),

        //Create a list of comments by duplicating each WS item Count times
            comments = 
                List.Combine(
                    List.Generate(
                        ()=>[c=List.Repeat({WS{0}}, WScnts{0}), idx=0],
                        each [idx] < List.Count(WS),
                        each [c=List.Repeat({WS{[idx]+1}}, WScnts{[idx]+1}), idx=[idx]+1],
                        each [c])),
//combine the Demand Qty and Comments columns into a new table
            results = Table.FromColumns(
                {Qty} & {comments}, 
                {"Demand Qty", "Commments"})       
        in
            results, type table[Demand Qty=Int64.Type, Commments=text]}
    }),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Group by Item",{"Index"}),
    #"Expanded new rows" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "new rows", {"Demand Qty", "Commments"})
in
    #"Expanded new rows"
```

***Source***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Getting this error:   Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value null to type Text.
Details:
    Value=
    Type=Type

Comment: @Myykro Probably has to do with how different your actual data set is from the example you initially posted. I suggested you post a ***realistic*** example **as text** which can be copy/pasted, and I'll take a closer look at it. (*Your screenshot is not useful as I cannot copy/paste that data into a worksheet*)

Comment: @Myykro I also see that your screenshot as a number of identical Items. How are you planning to handle that situation?  Treat each line separately?  Or lump together the identical items?

Comment: @Myykro I have edited my code that, hopefully, will deal with your problems. I assumed that, even with Identical "Items", that you wanted to keep each line separate.  I used a different method to identify the W/S items in the comments.  If it doesn't work on your real data, I will need a data sample that I can copy/paste and that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I've updated with question with a more realistic sample of data as text.

Comment: @Myykro OK, I have updated the code. The `can't convert null to text` error was because you had empty comments. I fix that by replacing **null** with `""` early in the routine.  Other errors would then show because, unlike your original example, the realistic example had multiple colons.  Also, since you did not answer that question, identical items are treated separately.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  They should be treated separately.

Comment: @Myykro So did the modification work?

Comment: For some reason it didn't like declaring the data type when adding the index column but once I took that out and tweaked a few other things it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Wawooweewa, what a fun challenge! I really had to finish my coffee to figure out the dates part.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReformatByLine()
    
    Dim I As Long               'Iteration Counter
    Dim N As Long               'Sub-Iteration Counter
    Dim X As Long               'Sub-Iteration Counter
    Dim DateCnt As Long         'Date Count
    Dim RowCnt As Long          'Row Count
    Dim OutCnt As Long          'OutArray Row Count
    Dim RG As Range             'Source Range
    Dim InArray()               'Data In Array
    Dim OutArray()              'Data Out Array
    Dim DateArray(1 To 50)      'Temp Array of Dates
    Dim DateString As String    'String Containing Dates
        
        ' >>> Collect data
    Set RG = Sheet1.Range("A4:C7")
    InArray = RG
    RowCnt = 0
    
        ' >>> Find expected upperbound of output array
    For I = 1 To UBound(InArray, 1)
        RowCnt = RowCnt + InArray(I, 2)
    Next I
    'Debug.Print RowCnt
    ReDim OutArray(1 To RowCnt, 1 To 4)
    
        ' >>> Begin data conversion
    OutCnt = 1
    For I = 1 To UBound(InArray, 1)
        
        ' > Extract date string from larger string
        DateString = Split(InArray(I, 3), ":")(1)
        DateString = Replace(DateString, " W/S ", "X")
        'Debug.Print DateString
        
        ' > Break apart dates
        If Len(DateString) = Len(Replace(DateString, "+", "")) Then
            For N = 1 To InArray(I, 2)
                DateArray(N) = Mid(DateString, InStr(1, DateString, "X", vbTextCompare) + 1, 50)
                'Debug.Print DateArray(N)
            Next N
        Else
            DateCnt = 1
            For N = 1 To UBound(Split(DateString, " + ")) + 1
                'Debug.Print "N=" & N
                'Debug.Print "For X = 1 to " & CInt(Split(Split(DateString, " + ")(N - 1), "X")(0))
                For X = 1 To CInt(Split(Split(DateString, " + ")(N - 1), "X")(0))
                    'Debug.Print "Date=" & Trim(Split(Split(DateString, " + ")(N - 1), "X")(1))
                    DateArray(DateCnt) = Trim(Split(Split(DateString, " + ")(N - 1), "X")(1))
                    DateCnt = DateCnt + 1
                Next X
            Next N
        End If
        
        ' > Build output array
        For N = 1 To InArray(I, 2)
            OutArray(OutCnt, 1) = InArray(I, 1)
            OutArray(OutCnt, 2) = 1
            OutArray(OutCnt, 3) = Split(InArray(I, 3), ":")(0)
            OutArray(OutCnt, 4) = DateArray(N)
            Debug.Print OutArray(OutCnt, 1) & " <> " & OutArray(OutCnt, 2) & " <> " & OutArray(OutCnt, 3) & " <> " & OutArray(OutCnt, 4)
            OutCnt = OutCnt + 1
        Next N
        
    Next I

    Sheet1.Range("E4").Resize(UBound(OutArray, 1), UBound(OutArray, 2)).Value = OutArray

End Sub
```

And here is the sheet I was working with. It shows both input and output.
I'm kind of assuming the format will always be the same, but it's easy to fix with some more code if not.

[image: VisualExample]

Comment: I assumed you might be doing more than one at a time, so I designed it to work with either singles or a multi line data set.

Comment: The actual data set is substantially larger.  When attempting to create an array from it, it throws an out of memory error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `mid` and `find` like so.

For quantity:

```
=MID($C$2,FIND("W/S",$C$2,FIND("W/S",$C$2)+1)-2,2)
```

This would only work for quantities up to 99.

[image]

For date:

```
=MID(C2,FIND("W/S",C2,FIND("W/S",C2)+1)+3,6)
```

[image]

Comment: It's a start!  So it works for the first and second instances but some comments have up to 6-7 instances of "W/S".  I tried adding one to the count and nesting FIND again but neither works.

Comment: The +1 is just to skip to the second occurrence. If you have 7 instances, you would have to build each one upon the last.